# Apple LLVM Compiler Error 4.1 [invalid deployment target for -stdlib=libc++]

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors, llvm-clang, llvm-c++-api

Can Any one Tell me how to solve this Error... My X-Code is Version 4.5. My IOS Simulator is Version 4.3

```
clang: error: invalid deployment target for -stdlib=libc++ (requires iOS 5.0 or later)
```

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130655/why-is-the-xcode-compiler-not-warning-me-about-invalid-methods-for-my-deployment

Answer (score 3):

In your case, Your Project is not support your default `deployment target` so, you need to change it (*if `5.0` deployment target not available then update your system*)

**This Screen Shot describe how to change  deployment target:**

[image]

All Step (*For Change `deployment target`*) are i added to this screen shot.

1) Select Project From your Project Navigation Bar
2) Select Project Targets
3) select **Summary** tab
4) select and change Deployment Target.

Answer (score 2):

Projects created using Xcode 4.5 use libc++ implementation of the standard C++ library. But the libc++ library is available only on iOS 5.0 and later, So, if you want to enable deployment on earlier releases of iOS in your project, set the C++ Standard Library build setting to libstdc++ (Gnu C++ standard library).